# How to require user login using htpasswd within the htaccess file?

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, web-development, security, authentication

I'm trying to require users to login and would like to handle the request with htpasswd in the htaccess file:

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the *.htpasswd* method via *.htaccess* file. You can see how to use it [here](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/):

> **Password Protection with htaccess**
>
> With .htaccess it is very easy to password protect a folder or
>   directory. The method is called htaccess password protection or
>   htaccess authentication, and works by uploading two files called
>   .htaccess and .htpasswd in the directory you want to password protect.
>   The htaccess file should contain the following:
>
> ```
> AuthType Basic
> AuthName "Password Protected Area"
> AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
> Require valid-user
> ```
>
> You only need to change “/path/to/.htpasswd” with the full path to
>   your .htpasswd. Take a look at my article on how to find the full path
>   using PHP. Next you need to upload the .htpasswd file which contains
>   the username and password to enter the password protected folder. The
>   .htpasswd file should contain:
>
> ```
> test:dGRkPurkuWmW2
> ```
>
> The above code will allow the user “test” to access the password
>   proteced area with the password “test”. The text “dGRkPurkuWmW2″ is a
>   encrypted version of the password. You will need to use a [htpasswd
>   generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) to create another password. Each line in the .htpasswd
>   file contains a username and password combination, so feel free to add
>   as many combinations as you like.
>
> **The automatic way – Use the generator**
>
> You can also just use the [htaccess authentication generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/) to
>   create a htaccess file for password protection.